# Last restart/start time of a windows service

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

Is it possible to find out in Windows what the last restart time of a windows service is?

Comment: you can also look at the process, and see when it started, and take the delta from sysuptime

Answer (score 28):

Building on Christian's answer... Use PowerShell:

```
(Get-EventLog -LogName "System" -Source "Service Control Manager" -EntryType "Information" -Message "*Computer Browser service*running*" -Newest 1).TimeGenerated;
```

Comment: Do any of these service state change events still get logged in Windows 10? (No entries generated for me when I do "net start spooler" for example.)

Answer (score 5):

Look in the event log: The service control manager logs every time a service is stopped or started.

Comment: This is Event Viewer -> Windows Logs -> System, where Source is Service Control Manager.

Comment: Not all services are listed in the Event Log, for example BitLocker Drive Encryption Service can be running by has no Event Log start entry.