# What is required for logging start/stop of the service?

Tags: logging, windows-10, windows-service

I would like to log entry when some service was started/stopped. For example this post ([Last restart/start time of a windows service](https://serverfault.com/questions/416536/last-restart-start-time-of-a-windows-service)) explains how to view logs.

The problem is, when I start/stop given service nothing is logged at all.

So probably I miss some option/configuration enabling the logging. Thus the question -- what is required for logging then?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to configure auditing on your services. This can be baked into your image or deployed to all computers using Group Policy. From the group policy editor, this is found at Computer Configuration->Policies->Windows Settings->Security Settings->System Services. [Source.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8ce6d5af-3f5c-4144-a20b-6ecd5a1d3d64/windows-services-auditing?forum=winserverDS)