# How to create a GPO to audit start/stop of a service not running on the DC?

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, domain-controller, windows-service, audit

I'm trying to enable auditing of service start/stop events for a few specific services on a group of domain computers, and to make this change using Group Policy.

I've seen [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/944343/what-is-required-for-logging-start-stop-of-the-service?rq=1) answer, however when I follow these steps on the DC, I'm only seeing services installed on the DC. My problem is, that I'm trying to audit services that are not installed on the DC.

How can I create a GPO with the Group Policy Management Editor connecting to another computer in the domain?

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer [here](https://microsoft.public.windows.server.active-directory.narkive.com/Mt8T4gzW/can-you-add-services-to-a-gpo-s-system-services-node).

In short, you need to create a security template (mmc, add snap-in) on a machine  that has the service, then import this template to the GPEditor where you are creating the GPO. You will need to refresh the view for the services to appear.